# v0.18.1 error , can't start network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

when I run

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -a test-network.bna -A admin -S adminpw
```

it took a long time then got a timeout error

```
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
```

docker ps

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
84daf56fde06        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0-rc1      "peer node start"        12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
a6835cf4ed34        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0-rc1   "orderer"                12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
3ab21e84dc6e        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6       "tini -- /docker-ent…"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
64acf6dc5db7        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0-rc1        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
```

$ docker logs peer0.org1.example.com

```
2018-03-15 03:02:51.419 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 4bf [composerchannel][9b4c096b] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" ,
error: timeout expired while starting chaincode test-network:0.18.1(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:9b4c096bcffd303acdafbc46ca17a2d69c33de917ccc0d47965b43dd67484960)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composer network start command is creating a new docker container and using npm install within that container, so your timeout could be a result of a slow system creating the container, and/or slow performance of the npm install command.

The default timeout is 300 seconds, but you can increase that value with the environment variable `CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=800s`

If you look at the docker-compose yaml file that is used to start your Fabric (specifically the Peer) then you can add an additional line for this environment variable.

If you are using the default Dev Fabric, the file you are looking for is probably: `~/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/docker-compose.yml`